# c# multiple colors in listview (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I making a listview in WPF and I want that it will display some items with multiple colors (example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi43d.png).
This is my listview with the columns:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Margin="0,27,0,0">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Server Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ServerName}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Players" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Players}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Map" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Map}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Game Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GameType}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Ip" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Ip}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I add the items with this code:

```
listView.Items.Add(new Server { ServerName = "GunMoney", Players = "0/16", Map = "ut4_asd", GameType = "FFA", Ip = "127.0.0.0:27960" });

public class Server
{
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    public string Players { get; set; }
    public string Map { get; set; }
    public string GameType { get; set; }
    public string Ip { get; set; }
}
```

I want to find a way that I can make a text like that: ^2Gun^3Money and it will display in diffrent colors(the ^2 say which color)

Comment: There are lots of ways. For example, create a `DataTemplate` that binds colors to properties that should affect those colors. Please research what's possible, make an attempt, and see how that goes. If you have a _specific_ problem doing that, please post a new question that includes [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces whatever problem you are having, along with a precise explanation of what the code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I did research some stuff in stackoverflow and in google but I didnt find a way to display dynamic text with more than one color.

Comment: when you want to display text with more than one style, that's called richtext. In WPF you can use spans to help you out. Examples: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-textblock-control-inline-formatting/

Comment: @PatrickKlug ok, how do I add custom textbox to my listview?

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand, you need some mechanism that translate the string ^2Gun^3Money to string color pairs collection and display this in data grid cell. If so here some solution of that problem:
 1. XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="SoGridViewHelpAttempt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:soGridViewHelpAttempt="clr-namespace:SoGridViewHelpAttempt"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ServerNameCellTemplate" DataType="soGridViewHelpAttempt:ServerNameObject">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ServerNamePartsCollection}" BorderBrush="#00000000" BorderThickness="2">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="soGridViewHelpAttempt:ServerNameParts">
                                <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" Text="{Binding NamePart}" Background="{Binding NamePartBrush}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </DataTemplate>
    <x:Array x:Key="ColorValuePairs" Type="soGridViewHelpAttempt:ColorAndKey">
        <soGridViewHelpAttempt:ColorAndKey Key="^1" Brush="Red"/>
        <soGridViewHelpAttempt:ColorAndKey Key="^2" Brush="Green"/>
        <soGridViewHelpAttempt:ColorAndKey Key="^3" Brush="Blue"/>
    </x:Array>
    <soGridViewHelpAttempt:ServerNameString2ColorNamePartValuesConverter x:Key="ServerNameString2ColorNamePartValuesConverterKey" BrushMap ="{StaticResource ColorValuePairs}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <soGridViewHelpAttempt:DataGridMAinViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="ListView" Margin="0,27,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding ServerDataCollection}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Server Name">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="soGridViewHelpAttempt:Server">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ServerNamePresenter" Content="{Binding ServerName, Converter={StaticResource ServerNameString2ColorNamePartValuesConverterKey}}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ServerNameCellTemplate}"></ContentControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Players" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Players}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Map" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Map}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Game Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GameType}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Ip" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Ip}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Explanation; 1) ServerNameCellTemplate is the data grid cell's template. This is a list box that displays the part of the name in a text block and define the text block brush based on provided key. 2)ServerNameString2ColorNamePartValuesConverter  converts the provided string to partial name and its brush objects. 3)ColorValuePairs available colors.
 2. ViewModel code (provide the ListView ItemsSource):

```
  public class DataGridMAinViewModel:BaseObservableObject
{
    public DataGridMAinViewModel()
    {
        ServerDataCollection = new ObservableCollection<Server>(new List<Server>
        {
            new Server { 
                ServerName = "^1Gun^3Money",
            Players = "0/16", Map = "ut4_asd", GameType = "FFA", Ip = "127.0.0.0:27960" },
             new Server { ServerName = "^2Gun^1Money",
            Players = "0/16", Map = "ut4_asd", GameType = "FFA", Ip = "127.0.0.0:27960" },
             new Server { ServerName = "^2Gun^3Money",
            Players = "0/16", Map = "ut4_asd", GameType = "FFA", Ip = "127.0.0.0:27960" },
        });
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Server> ServerDataCollection { get; set; }
}
```

3. Server model:

```
public class Server:BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _serverName;
    private string _players;
    private string _map;
    private string _gameType;
    private string _ip;

    public string ServerName
    {
        get { return _serverName; }
        set
        {
            _serverName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Players
    {
        get { return _players; }
        set
        {
            _players = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Map
    {
        get { return _map; }
        set
        {
            _map = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string GameType
    {
        get { return _gameType; }
        set
        {
            _gameType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public string Ip
    {
        get { return _ip; }
        set
        {
            _ip = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

4. Converters and its models:

```
    public class ServerNameString2ColorNamePartValuesConverter : IValueConverter
{


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var name = value.ToString();
        var verbalNameParts = name.Split(BrushMap.Select(item => item.Key).ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var colorKeyNameParts = name.Split(verbalNameParts, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (verbalNameParts.Length != colorKeyNameParts.Length) return null;
        var index = 0;
        var nameMappedToColors = new ObservableCollection<ServerNameParts>();
        verbalNameParts.ToList().ForEach(namePart =>
        {
            var brush = BrushMap.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Key == colorKeyNameParts[index]);
            if(brush == null) return;
            nameMappedToColors.Add(new ServerNameParts
           {
               NamePart = namePart,
               NamePartBrush = brush.Brush,
           });
            index++;
        });

        return new ServerNameObject{ServerNamePartsCollection = nameMappedToColors};
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ColorAndKey[] BrushMap { get; set; }
}

public class ColorAndKey
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public Brush Brush { get; set; }
}

public class ServerNameObject : BaseObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<ServerNameParts> ServerNamePartsCollection { get; set; }
}

public class ServerNameParts : BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _name;
    private Brush _namePartBrush;


    public Brush NamePartBrush
    {
        get { return _namePartBrush; }
        set
        {
            _namePartBrush = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string NamePart
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

5. BaseObservableObject is the simple implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

```
public class BaseObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> raiser)
    {
        var propName = ((MemberExpression)raiser.Body).Member.Name;
        OnPropertyChanged(propName);
    }

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(name);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The solution is provided by converters that converts the string to object that we can template in xaml. I hope it will help you.
Regards,